# Correlation.. covariance.. I am so lost

Tags: self-study, correlation, variance, covariance

This monday I'll take my exam in Investment analyses. My teacher usually gives a matrix with covariances and beta's, which makes it easy to find Expected return/ Variance. He just posted some exam prep questions. I've been failing to solve some of them. Any chance somebody could try to safe the day?

Given:
The annual expected excess return on the market
portfolio equals 5.50% with a volatility of 13% and the risk free rate is 2% annually.

Risky asset A Risky asset B Market Portfolio
**Cov Asset A and B is 0.0116** 
Cov Asset A and market is 0.0154
**Cov Asset B and market is 0.0115**

Correlation between asset A and the market portfolio is 0.95 and the
correlation between asset B and the market portfolio is 0.63.

-> Capm holds 
-> Equal weighted portfolio (50% A 50% B)

Calculate Expected return and volitility.

I'm not expecting anybody to solve the questions for me. I'm just very confused how to determine Variance with the given information. Anybody got any tips how to solve this?

Comment: You need to use the self study tag.  We can only provide hints and more details about what the questions are and where you are having trouble could help us give hints.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michael. I added the self study tag. I'm unsure how to even start this question with the very limited information given :(.

Comment: How about the concepts in your title?  Covariance and correlation are measures of relationships between random variables.  Correlation ranges between -1 and 1,  The value 1 represents a perfect linear relationship with positive slope. -1 denotes a perfect linear relationship with negative slope. For two random variables X and Y  Cov(X,Y) =Cor(X,Y) x sqrt(Var[X] x Var[Y].

Comment: It is extremely hard to determine the question given what you have written here. I have no clue what **"Risky asset A Risky asset B Market Portfolio Cov Asset A and B is 0.0116..."**  is saying. This can't be the way the exam prep question was written. I guess that it's describing a covariance matrix but it's not a sentence and it doesn't make sense. Where are the variances? Maybe you should take a screenshot of the question and post it here. I suspect this has something to do with calculating the variance of a sum, which equals the sum of the variances plus twice the covariance.

Answer (score 0):

Given your (poorly written) question, I can try and gauge what you've asked.

Given the CAPM holds, we know:

$$\begin{align}
E[R_{i}]&=R_{f}+\beta_{i}(E[R_{M}]-R_{f})
\end{align}$$
where $E[R_{i}]$ is the expected return on asset $i$, $R_{f}$ is the risk-free rate of interest, $E[R_{M}]$ is the expected return on the market and $\beta_{i}$ is the sensitivity of the **excess returns of the asset** to **excess returns of the market**.

Using very basic portfolio theory, a portfolio comprised of weights, $w_{i}$, of Asset A and Asset B has return:

$$\begin{align}
R_{p}&=w_{A}R_{A}+w_{B}R_{B}
\end{align}$$

Taking the expectation gives:

$$\begin{align}
E[R_{p}]&=w_{A}E[R_{A}]+w_{B}E[R_{B}]
\end{align}$$

The variance of the portfolio is given by:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(R_{p})&=\text{Var}(w_{A}R_{A}+w_{B}R_{B})\\
&=w_{A}^{2}\text{Var}(R_{A})+w_{B}^{2}\text{Var}(R_{B})+2w_{A}w_{B}\text{Cov}(R_{A},R_{B})
\end{align}$$

Keep in mind the relationship between $\beta_{i}$, $\text{Cov}(R_{i})$ and $\text{Var}(R_{M})$:

$$\begin{align}
\beta_{i}&=\frac{\text{Cov}(R_{i},R_{M})}{\text{Var}(R_{M})}\\
\end{align}$$

And that generally:

$$\begin{align}
\rho_{R_{i},R_{j}}&=\frac{\text{Cov}(R_{i},R_{j})}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(R_{i})\text{Var}(R_{j})}}\\
\end{align}$$

where $\rho_{R_{i},R_{j}}$ is the correlation coefficient between $R_{i}$ and $R_{j}$.